# Leetcode Rotate Array works differently in codepen

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've solved one of Leetcode problems in codepen, but when I try to submit it on leetcode I get a different result than what I get in codepen.

The problem is:

```
Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k = 3
Output: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
Explanation:
rotate 1 steps to the right: [7,1,2,3,4,5,6]
rotate 2 steps to the right: [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]
rotate 3 steps to the right: [5,6,7,1,2,3,4]
```

Link (requires login) https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/646/

My solution:

```
var rotate = function(nums, k) {
  var a = nums.splice(0 , nums.length-k);
  var b = nums.splice(-k);
  var c = [...b , ...a ];
  return(c);
};
```

Using the above example, running this code on codepen returns (or console.logs) [5,6,7,1,2,3,4].

But when I run this code in leetcode, I get an empty array [].

Any ideas why this could be the happening?

Comment: Read carefully: `@return {void} Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.`

Comment: Also `.slice` and `.splice` are completely different.

Comment: Using splice mutates the array, using slice doesn't. Take a look at which one you need as the first `nums.splice` is changing the content of your original array. Take a look at the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Hint: you need exactly one `.splice` to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It looks like you're supposed to rotate the original array, not return a new rotated array. So you need to set `nums = [...b, ...a]` instead.</strike>

EDIT: Since JavaScript passes by value, the `nums` parameter just holds a reference to the original array, so doing `nums = []` will only change the `nums` variable to reference a different array, without changing the original array. You'll want to call methods of the original array to mutate it. E.g. `.splice`

/EDIT

Also, have you thought about what happens when `k` is greater than the length of the array? E.g. `nums = [1, 2, 3], k = 5`

Also also, your link to leetcode requires login, so not everyone will be able to view it.

Comment: I did:
  nums = [...b , ...a ];
  return(nums);
and got the same results

Comment: Assigning to `nums` doesn't modify the original array. JS parameters are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, that always gets me.

Answer (score 1):

### Example A

`.pop()` removes the last element of an array and returns it. `.unshift()` the returned value of `.pop()` to the first index of the array. Do that `k` times in  a `for` loop. `.pop()` and `.unshift()` changes (aka mutates) the original array.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], k = 3;

function rotate(array, times) {
  for (let i=0; i < times; i++) {
    let last = array.pop();
    array.unshift(last);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(rotate(arr, k));
```

### Example B

By changing `.splice()` to `.slice()` you can implement your logic since `.slice()` creates a shallow copy of the array and does not mutate the original array like `.splice()`. Since the original array is unchanged, any references to said array are consistent. Also, concerning the case mentioned in [LawrenceWebDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891765/2813224) -- if `k` is greater than the length of the array -- `k` (`times`) becomes the remainder of `k/array.length` (`times % size`).

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], k = 3;

function rotate(array, times) {
  const size = array.length;
  if (times > size) {
    times = times % size;
  }
  let a = array.slice(-times);
  let b = array.slice(0, size - times);
  return [...a, ...b];
}

console.log(rotate(arr, k));
```

Comment: This is an O(N^2) algorithm because `unshift()` is O(N), so it probably will get a TLE at LeetCode.

Comment: @Barmar yes, this does give me the correct output when I "run code" on leetcode, but I get a TLE error when I "submit" the solution.

Comment: O(N) is how I think -- methodically slow 

Comment: @Baslki just updated answer, try **Example B** which goes along with the OP logic.

Comment: @zer00ne I appreciate your time, however Example B returns [5,6,7,1,2,3,4] in CodePen, but return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] in Leetcode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Leetcode , BTW what is a TLE?

Comment: @zer00ne it's "Time Limit Exceeded". BTW I tried one of the official solutions posted by leetcode, and I got the TLE. I think it's an issue with leetcode.